# Node worker thread can't load external module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency

I'm trying to multi-thread a cpu-intense job on my server. I'm using webworker-threads.

Server.js: (the relevant parts)

```
var Worker = require('webworker-threads').Worker;
function doWork(req, res)
{   
    console.log("connection received");
    var fibo = new Worker('plainworker.js');

    fibo.onmessage = function (event) {
        res.json('fib(10) = ' + event.data);
    };

    fibo.postMessage(10);
}
```

plainworker.js:

```
var _ = require('underscore'); ///////////// <---- PROBLEM LINE

function fibo (n) {
          return n > 1 ? fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2) : 1;
        }
onmessage = function (event) {
  postMessage(fibo(event.data));
}
```

So I've noticed that if I have a module loaded in my plainworker.js file then it freaks out and stalls. If I remove this line then everything works ok. Problem is, I want to use underscore within my worker...

Does anyone have experience with either threads-a-gogo or webworker-threads and can tell me if they have successfully loaded an external module WITHIN the worker thread?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: no error, it just causes the server to hang if I include the line var _ = require('underscore');

Comment: Could you load it in the server and then just pass it as a param to the plainworker methods that need it? Is it any require? Or just `require('underscore')`?

Comment: Nope passing it in doesn't work either. ANY require doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like I had to use 'importScripts(..)' function ([see here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/webworker-threads)), as require doesnt seem to work within a worker thread.

plainworker.js:

```
importScripts('./node_modules/underscore/underscore.js');

function fibo (n) {
          return n > 1 ? fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2) : 1;
        }
onmessage = function (event) {
  postMessage(fibo(event.data));
}
```

Comment: this worked for me - the path to underscore is relative to the worker.js file...but it will fail silently

Comment: any recent solutions for using `import` or `require` in worker threads in latest node.js?

Comment: @datdinhquoc any solution?

Comment: @m4heshd i haven't found 1 yet, seems worker threads work with vanilla js only

Comment: @datdinhquoc For me, requiring packages worked but not files because I'm using eval. I just realized that. So I sent the absolute path to the file as `workerData` and required it inside the worker. Works like a charm.